# Implementing Project structure using EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, project

I am trying to implement the project structure as explained in the following blog:

[The blog](http://www.toplinestrategies.com/dotneters/net/wcf-entity-framework-and-n-tier-solutions-part-2/?lang=en/comment-page-1/#comment-1954)

First i will explain my goal:
I am trying to create the following structure using EntityFramework 5

- DAL - Include the EF 5
- Model layer - include the POCO classes generated from the EF 5
- MVC Project - Presentation layer

Now, this blog explain how doing it with EF 4, but in EF 5 there is no way to cut and paste the POCO entities is a different project.

Next i would like to create Metadata classes which extend the POCO entities

I have done the following:

- Created a class project called ("DAL") and created EF5 from database
- Created POCO entities from the edmx file
- Created a different class project called "ModelLayer"

Now my problem is that i can't move the MyEntities.tt file from the DAL project to the "DataModel" project

Next i would like to create a Metadata classes which extend the POCO entities

Does any one succeed doing it?

Comment: Why do you need an edmx file for your classes? Can't you just write the POCO classes yourself and remove that dependency?

Comment: How can i write the POCO entities if i want to work with EF5 database first?

Comment: EF power tools can generate poco classes from a database. Or is this an EF entity setup from a separate project?

Comment: I can do that if the EF5 and the POCO entities are sitting in the same project. But i want to separate them so the EF5 sits in DAL project and the POCO entities sit in DataModelLayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the .tt template file, at the top of the template file change the folowing line to point to your edmx file location in relative to your file structure

in my template file it's at line 5 (VB.Net) :

```
Const inputFile As String = "..\..\..\SFHDDATA\OP.edmx"
```

My edmx file is located here :

C:!DEV\SFHD\Branches\iGEDIA_2\iGEDIA_2\SFHDDATA

My other project with the tt file is here :

C:!DEV\SFHD\Branches\iGEDIA_2\iGEDIA_2\SFHDModel\AGG\POCO

When you recompile if you're not pointing at the right folder you'll get an error message.

use @ before your path if you're using c#